# Cannot start Jetty 11 websocket server on OSGi

Tags: websocket, jetty, osgi

We have been using OSGi and Felix in the OW2/Joram project for many years. We have a working setup with Felix (7.0.5), Jetty 9.4, Felix Http and Jetty websocket bundles. Recently we upgraded our libraries to JEE 10: Jetty 11.0.18, Jersey 3.1.3, Felix Http (5.1.6). Our Rest services work correctly on this new platform, unfortunately we cannot find a working configuration for our websockets server.

We found a minimum configuration:

> felix.auto.start.1= 
> file:./bundle/slf4j-api.jar 
> file:./bundle/slf4j-jdk14.jar 
> file:./bundle/jetty-xml.jar 
> file:./bundle/jetty-webapp.jar 
> file:./bundle/websocket-jetty-api.jar 
> file:./bundle/websocket-jetty-common.jar 
> file:./bundle/websocket-core-common.jar 
> file:./bundle/websocket-servlet-11.0.18.jar 
> file:./bundle/websocket-core-server-11.0.18.jar 
> file:./bundle/websocket-jetty-server.jar 
> file:./bundle/org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api.jar 
> file:./bundle/org.apache.felix.log.jar 
> file:./bundle/org.apache.felix.http.jetty.jar

But during startup we have the following errors:

> ERROR: Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.webapp [4] Error starting file:./bundle/jetty-webapp.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.eclipse.jetty.webapp [4](R 4.0): missing requirement [org.eclipse.jetty.webapp [4](R 4.0)] osgi.extender; (osgi.extender=osgi.serviceloader.processor) Unresolved requirements: [[org.eclipse.jetty.webapp [4](R 4.0)] osgi.extender; (osgi.extender=osgi.serviceloader.processor)])

> ERROR: Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common [6] Error starting file:./bundle/websocket-jetty-common.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common [6](R 6.0): missing requirement [org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common [6](R 6.0)] osgi.extender; (osgi.extender=osgi.serviceloader.registrar) Unresolved requirements: [[org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common [6](R 6.0)] osgi.extender; (osgi.extender=osgi.serviceloader.registrar)])

The 2 errors above seem to be due to OSGi extensions requested by the "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp" and "org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common" bundles. Are they necessary?
The last error during launch concerns the "org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server" bundle which cannot be started because the previous bundles above have not been started.

I have also unsuccessfully tried using Felix scr to try to resolve this issue. Does anyone have the solution to start a Jetty websocket server with OSGi and more especially Felix?

Comment: You need osgi.serviceloader.registrar/osgi.serviceloader.extender implementation. For example https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/aries/spifly/org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle/

Comment: Thanks, after adding spifly (and its dependencies) all bundles are now resolved correctly.